# Outlook 2013 detected a slow addin

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I developed an Addin which consists of Login and the data entry and retrieval functionality. The data entry and retrieval are accessed through REST URL's. The Outlook Startup doesnt has any code, except it checks the outlook version. I implement a plain form which show the user "loading message" initially and the rest of the logic will be handled by a thread. So i hope everything is followed according to the performance, but still  i am receiving an addon error as "Outlook Detected an Addin Problem" The Add-in caused outlook to start slowly. I am able to overcome this problem and more and more i am able to get the time statistics for application start or shutdown events. could[image]any help me how do i resolve this?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue.  I can't even intentionally induce this error  when I make the main thread sleep for a 10 seconds during the onStartUp event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying your AddIn in a debug mode or through an installer ?

First of all, make sure that it has been disabled because it is slow and not because it has errors.

If it has errors, it will cause Outlook to work slowly or even crash.

If it just working slowly, you can try to optimize your AddIn, go through your code again and see what you can do again in a less performance consuming way.

One other thing you can do is, when you will create a setup project for your AddIn to run an installer (instead of debug), you can set your Load Behavior to 16 in the registry.

This will cause the AddIn to load at Outlook startup on the first time after installation and to load on demand the other times. (Load on demand means when the user clicks on the AddIn icon).

This way, your AddIn won't slow Outlook down, except for the first time.